# How do I get Mono to work in Ubuntu server

Tags: apache2, mono

I am trying to get mono to work so I can load my `apache2` web page from visual studio.

I have a server that is connected to the network and I can't seem to get visual studio to load to the server. I am not sure if I have `Mono` placed in the wrong file or if I am linking it up wrong. If you know how to place the mono file and which one I actually need (I used `Mono 4.5` and placed the conf file in `/etc/apache2`) I would really appreciate it.

Response to @Letizia,

If by include you mean did I move the file, Yes, I used

```
  mv /etc/mono/mono.conf /etc/apache2/
```

If I go to the desktop and look at the files I can see the `mono 4.5` file in the `apache2` folder. However, do I need to move the mono `web.conf` to the `apache2.conf`?

I don't know, something doesn't seem right about that setup, adding more code to the `Apache2` conf file.

Like I said, the `mono 4.5` file is in the `etc/apache2` folder, next to `config-available` folder and `conf-enabled` folder.

Another thing that is holding me up is that my network is not on the `127.0.0.1` (localhost) my localhost has a different `192.168.x.x` because I am behind two routers.

I have the network taken care of and port 80 is forwarded and secure.

I just think I am missing something and I can't put my finger on it.

Maybe is in the configuration of the web form when I get ready to deploy my page from visual studio. Like, if I have the server and file paths correctly inputted. That too has raised a question or two in me.

Comment: Did you include /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf in apache2.conf?

Comment: Yes, look at my edit.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. YOU JUST OVERWROTE YOUR APACHE CONFIG?!?!??

Comment: NO, I did not over write anything...Apache still works...The folder is in apapche2, I didn't place anything in the apache2 config yet.the code was an typo, I didn't place it in etc/apache2/apache2.conf. I placed it in etc/apache2

Comment: Oh, thank god. You got me worried there. Can you edit that please?

Comment: Here is a useful link on how to install and configure [mono on ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono)

Comment: Edit taken care of, sorry for the heart attack. It seems that I may not have mod-mono installed, but I thought it came with mono-complete?

Comment: It seems that mono may disable PHP. I would be able to get that back if I wanted to reinstall it after I implemented the Web page, right? Of Course I would have to uninstall mono, but I would at least be able to accomplish what I need and then revert back to the original settings. I hope.

Comment: It seems that `libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server2` comes back with error @MyServer:~$ `libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server2`
libapache2-mod-mono: command not found. I tried using the sudo also, I can install the Non-Auto Hosting but that is not what I want. THat uses the apt-get install directive. I am running Ubuntu server 14.04.01. That install code was for 12. I cant seem to find one for 14, or should that even matter?

Comment: Never mind, I know what I did wrong...I have it installed, everything is up as far as mono-appache 2 are concerned, however, I am having problems figuring out the correct file paths and server location to use now in order for me to be able to load my page from another client, but this client is on the same network, just not physically connected.

Comment: So, now you installed successfully mod_mono? Did you enable it?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I can not get Visual studio to deploy the web page to my server. I am not sure I am using the right "location to publish file" and the right "URL". I have three options. I can use a file system, Local IIS, or FTP Site. I have tried all.Do I have to enable something in the sites-available file or the apache2 conf file?

Comment: I am trying something with the IIS configuration now. I think this is where the problem lies. Will let you know the results.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/#manual-modmono-configuration)

Comment: I think what i need is the correct way to add in the "location to publish file" and the correct "URL". like I said, my server is not on 172.0.0.1 on my client server that I am sending the web page with. It is on 127.0.0.1 on its own server, but if I set the path in VS to 127.0.0.1 it thinks it is staying on the same computer. You understand what I mean? what would be the proper paths to use to send this web page, and from there I could maybe figure it out. I am looking at the link you sent and that is what I was saying before, I need to change something. So, I think it is a combo of both

Comment: OK, I need some help. the link you provided just confused me a bit more. What would I put in the location for my deployment if I was using the default apache2 web page? Moreover, the files that need to be placed are already in place. I dont get it.

Comment: I need some clarification to help you. Let's see if I understand: there is ubuntu 14.04 where you installed apache 2.4 and mod_mono. This Ubuntu is inside lan and ip address is 192.168.x.x. You are developing C# code on windows PC using Visual studio. Is this windows PC on the same lan of ubuntu? Tell me if this assertions are right and post on http://pastebin.com/ these files: apache2.conf and 00-default.conf if exists.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and Visual Studio is on the same LAN behind the same router. This router goes to a Router/gateway that accesses the internet. I have the routing situation taken care of, everything is fine with that I believe. The files are posted to the site under Apache2-000-Conf/Help

Comment: I did not found you file on http://pastebin.com/Apache2-000-Conf/Help.

Comment: Letizia, reposted it under Apache2 and 000-conf file.

Comment: Sorry for delay, could you post url where I can find configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Mono is an Apache mod, akin to PHP.

To enable it, only run `a2enmod mono`.

Comment: I will try it, but like I said above, I did not place anything in the apache2 conf file. I just moved the mono 4.5 folder over to /etc/apache2 folder, so apache is still running fine and my site default page is till visible

Comment: I get this error, :~$ sudo a2enmod mono
ERROR: Module mono does not exist!

Comment: @bri_ryche You need to install the module: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono`

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, do these step by step to install pre-requisites to run ASP.NET pages using apache webserver

```
:~$ apt-get install apache2
:~$ apt-get install mono-complete
:~$ apt-get install mono-apache-server2
:~$ apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono
```

Now, enable the module in apache

```
:~$ a2enmod mod_mono
```

Try enabling automatically when apache starts

```
:~$ a2enmod mod_mono_auto
```

Now, restart the server as usual

```
:~$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now, write some aspx pages and host it in standard directory /var/www and access using http://localhost/myfile.aspx